# Meteor accounts-password makes my app crash

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-accounts

I create a new app

```
meteor create myapp
```

then

```
cd my app
meteor add accounts-password
```

myapp is empty, nothing in there, only the default stuff, and when I run it it happens

```
W20170719-00:31:41.432(-5)? (STDERR) /home/myuser/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.1.vcnq6u++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
W20170719-00:31:41.433(-5)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20170719-00:31:41.434(-5)? (STDERR)                        ^
W20170719-00:31:41.436(-5)? (STDERR) 
W20170719-00:31:41.436(-5)? (STDERR) TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of undefined
W20170719-00:31:41.438(-5)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.accounts-password.password_server.js (packages/accounts-password/password_server.js:4:35)
W20170719-00:31:41.439(-5)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:333:9)
W20170719-00:31:41.439(-5)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:228:16)
W20170719-00:31:41.440(-5)? (STDERR)     at /myapppath/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/accounts-password.js:1227:1
W20170719-00:31:41.441(-5)? (STDERR)     at /myapppath/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/accounts-password.js:1233:3
W20170719-00:31:41.442(-5)? (STDERR)     at /myapppath/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:338:34
W20170719-00:31:41.443(-5)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20170719-00:31:41.444(-5)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/myuser/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.1.vcnq6u++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20170719-00:31:41.445(-5)? (STDERR)     at /myapppath/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:158:5
W20170719-00:31:41.447(-5)? (STDERR)     at /myapppath/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:387:5
```

any idea?
I have installed accounts.password many times in other apps, but right now I have no idea whats happening

Comment: did you run `meteor npm i` before ?

Comment: yes I did ran that command

Comment: Is `bcrypt` in your npm packages ?

Comment: no, but when bcrypt is missing another message appears about been slower without it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalled meteor and it worked.
After a day with no answers(tried everything I could imagine (downgrading meteor, downgrading packages, adding packages in different order and so forth)) and headaques.

Answer (score 2):

You have to run the command :

`meteor npm install`

to install the npm packages before launching your app.

See the meteor guide : https://guide.meteor.com/#quickstart

Comment: I did that and nothing, still crashing